Checking interface property value is valid
At runtime, I want to check that an object conforms to a specific interface. That is to say, each property in the object has the allowed values.
For example, this should fail since nope is not a valid
enum Switch {
  'on',
  'off',
}

interface Foo {
  State: Switch
}

const f: Foo = {
  State: 'nope'
}

This would fail at compile time, but I care about run time.
I thought type predicates were the way to go, but from my understanding, those are used to determine the kind of interface, not to validate an interface's properties.
enum Switch {
  'on',
  'warn',
}

interface Foo {
  Bar: number | Switch
}

const isValid = (foo: any): foo is Foo => {
  return (foo as Foo) !== undefined
}

console.log(isValid({ Bar: 'nope' }))

Is there any way I can validate these values without having to iterate over each of them individually?

All of the type metadata is erased in transpilation, it's only JS at runtime. You're probably best using an actual validation library (most of which are now also strongly typed).

You will need to use (or write) a runtime validator like zod.
